# ASP pie chart add label with value

Tags: c#, charts

I am making a pie chart & getting the values from Data Table. Here is my code :

.aspx code

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="500px">
                        <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </Series>
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                            </asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
```

.cs code

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie; 
Chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Emboss";
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true; 

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;

        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySQLConnection"].ToString();
    con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name, COUNT(code) AS quantity from vTable GROUP BY Name", con1);
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);

        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "quantity";
        Chart1.DataBind();
```

I want to show both label with its value on the pie chart. Name column in the SQL query should be shown as label & quantity as value. How it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [`DataPointCollection.DataBindXY(IEnumerable, IEnumerable[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example:

```
        string[] Names = new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };
        double[] Values = new double[] { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 };
        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Names, Values);
```

Hope that get you in the right direction!